# Find corners of a triangle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, corner-detection

I'm trying to find the pixel values of the corners of these triangles.
I can mark the points on the output image but don't know how to obtain it as variable for printing. I want these corner values to be stored in a variable.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r07Jo.png) is the input image "triangles.png". [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnBmd.png) is the output image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
filename = 'triangles.png'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
##result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[250,0,0]
cv2.imshow('dst',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what's wrong with the example in the documentation? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html

Answer (score 2):

```
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)
x, y = np.nonzero(dst > 0.01 * dst.max())
```

x, y - numpy arrays with x and y coordinates of corners. you can use it later:

```
coordinates = zip(x, y)
```